# Modulo of exponentiation by square in Javascript not working correctly?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, modulo

For the past several hours I've been trying to implement [Exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) in Javascript. Basically I've been trying to apply the [Fermat Little Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) to solve the modular multiplicative inverse. It seems like it should be straight forward yet I'm getting incorrect results:

```
const MAX = 10**9 + 7
const inv2 = expBySquare(2, MAX-2)
// inv2 should be 500000004 but is 437533240

function expBySquare(x, n) {
  if (n < 0) throw 'error'
  if (n === 0) return 1
  if (n === 1) return x

  if (n % 2 === 0) return expBySquare((x * x) % MAX, n / 2) % MAX
  return (x * expBySquare((x * x) % MAX, (n - 1) / 2)) % MAX
}
```

I've just tried to implement the algorithm in C https://onlinegdb.com/H1tsx4TY7 and it worked without problems. I knew that I should expected problems with overflows in JS but I think that it can handle the numbers since the modulo is used in all the weak points.

Comment: Not overflows but error accumulation (perhaps due to JS floats instead of true integers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I knew that I should expected problems with overflows in JS but I think that it can handle the numbers since the modulo is used in all the weak points.

JavaScript doesn't actually have a distinct "integer" type with "overflow"; rather, it just has a "number" type, whose values are double-precision floating-point numbers and are subject to roundoff error. So even if the value of `x * x` is representable as a 64-bit integer, it may not be exactly representable as a JavaScript number. JavaScript numbers can exactly represent any integer in the range [−(2<sup>53</sup> −1), 2<sup>53</sup> −1] — see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER — but your calculation involves values outside that range.

To see for yourself that you're venturing outside that range, you can insert this:

```
if (x * x > Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)
    throw 'error: ' + x + ' * ' + x + ' is ' + (x * x);
```

You will see `error: 294967268 * 294967268 is 87005689191383820` even though 294,967,268 × 294,967,268 is actually 8,7005,689,191,383,82**4**.

To fix this, you either need a smaller value of `MAX` (to ensure that `MAX * MAX <= Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`), or to use a (partial) big-integer library to perform integer arithmetic on the large values you're using.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript numbers always use a 64-bit floating point format. Hence, you can only work with a mantissa of 52 bits, which give you effective 53 bits. The intermediate values in your scenario exceed those, which will introduce rounding errors. The first time this happens is the squaring of `279,632,277`. This should be `78,194,210,340,204,729` (57 bit) but gets rounded to `78,194,210,340,204,730`.